# Find a multiplier which multiplies given indices into a formation of bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, computer-science, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a set of indices and a set of bit masks (the size of the sets is the same, and between 6-4096 but much closer to the lower bound). I also have a single bit mask which I will call the superset. I need to find a factor, that if for any index I have, if I multiply the factor and the index and mask bitand with the superset, the result is the subset. The masks and factor will all be 64-bit wide. This example is 8-bit cause I can't write 64-bit masks here obviously

```
mask = 00111000         ((p * index) & mask) == subset
index=3 sub=00010000 => ((p * 3) & mask) == 00010000
index=5 sub=00100000 => ((p * 5) & mask) == 00100000
```

Really, my input is just a set {i0, i1, ... iN} of indices, {s0, s1, ... sN} of masks, and a superset mask.
Of course, all the subsets are subsets of the super-set.  For now, for different indices, there can be the same subset results, but I will be happy to receive solutions that act as if this was not a constraint.

My best try for now is just guessing random numbers for the factor, and checking to see for each indice-subset pair if it holds true. If not, I go to the next number. But for the smallest form of this problem, I had 13 such pairs, but since the brute force algorithm is `O(2^n)` with a very large constant factor, I can't find a factor which holds true even for 7 pairs!

What I thought about is looking at the resulting values from the multiplication. Let's look at this problem from an 8-bit form: (Here a,b,c,d, etc mean if the i'th bit is set in the result of the multiplication)

```
P * Index = 2^0*a + 2^1*b + 2^2*c + 2^3*d + 2^4*e + 2^5*f + 2^6*g + 2^7*h
P = (1a + 2b + 4c + 8d + 16e + 32f + 64g + 128h) / Index
Now we want P to be integer, so do modulo (let's say Index is 5 for example)
P = (1a + 2b + 4c + 3d + 1e + 2f + 4g + 3h) / 5
P = (1(a+e) + 2(b+f) + 4(c+g) + 3(d+h)) / 5
```

So now we can say that every bit-mask that its sum of set bits multiplied by the coefficients above modulo 5 is 0, it's a valid P * Index, then we can find P by a simple division. Hope you get me.

But the problem is I don't know how to extend this to multiple index-result pairs, and I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: Recommendation: Remove the *Can anyone help me please?* [It's a question killer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4581301).

Comment: Can you please define clearly what are the inputs and outputs you want? Like a pseudo C code maybe? The description is a bit confusion right now. Is it a vector of indexes and a vector of masks (int64_t)?

Comment: @vvv444 In the 4-bit land. The superset is 0110, the inputs would be 2->0010, 4->0100, the factor would be 2. Because (2 * 2) & 0110 = 0010 AND (2 * 4) & 0110 = 0100. That's really a basic example though, I am looking for 64-bit and with tens to hundreds pairs of input.

Comment: Ok, is my understanding correct? Inputs: Indexes `{ i0,...iN }`, Subsets `{ s0, ... sN }`, superset - `mask`. Required output `p` that holds the conditions above?

Comment: @vvv444 Yup. Indexes are 9-bit numbers which I can try to manipulate to become prime, highly composite, small, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SMT solver like z3 for this. You can create variables for all the things you want calculated and then set constraints on them. Here I'm assuming that the values you can choose are p and the indices, that is still not clear from your question. Completely untested example:

```
void solve(const std::vector<uint64_t>& subs, uint64_t mask) {
    using namespace z3;
    context c;
    solver s(c);
    expr p = c.bv_const("p", 64);
    std::vector<expr> indices;
    for (int i = 0; i < subs.size(); ++i)
        indices.push_back(c.bv_const(("indices_" + std::to_string(i)).c_str(), 9));

    for (int i = 0; i < subs.size(); ++i)
        s.add((p * zext(indices[i], 64 - 9) & mask) == subs[i]);

    if (s.check() == sat) {
        model m = s.get_model();
        uint64_t p_result = m.eval(p).get_numeral_uint64();
        std::vector<uint16_t> indices_result;
        for (int i = 0; i < subs.size(); ++i)
           indices_result.push_back(m.eval(indices[i]).get_numeral_uint64());
        // do something with the result
    } else {
        // no solution
    }
}
```